# Error: Cannot find module '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

```
var express = require('express');
app = express(),
jade = require('jade'),
path = require('path'),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
users = [];

//view engine
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', jade);
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);

//static path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//index route
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});

server.listen('3000');
console.log('server started..');
```

I followed a video tutorial, I did the same thing but I got an error of cannot find module of [object Object]. The guy who did the video didn't include require('jade'), it worked for him, but it doesn't work for me. I says jade is not defined if I did not require jade.

Answer (score 11):

Not relevant to this case, but might assist someone.

I had this problem, and found that a mistake in

```
app.set('view engine', ejs);
```

caused it.

it should have been:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: Thanks, that at least partially solved the problem I came here for.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
var express = require('express');
```

into

```
var express = require('express'),
```

Right now `express` is the only variable that is defined.

Comment: nice catch, I fixed my typo but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try to install jade with both npm install jade and npm install jade -g to see what happens? It seems there are some issues with loading one of your modules. Do you perhaps get other / more elaborate errors then the one in your question?

Comment: I pasted in my whole code. I found the fix, the jade should have `'` like `'jade'`lol!

Comment: Nice! I've watched your code for quite a while, but couldn't find that one :).

Answer (score 0):

Need not import ejs module. Just pass string 'ejs' to the view engine. It will pick the module with the engine name given.

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

remove the importing module

```
jade = require('jade');
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to keep in mind you need:
Change this:

```js
app = express(),
app.set('view engine', jade);
```

to:

```js
app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
app.set('view engine', jade);
```

Into:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

And

```
app = express(),
```

Into:

```
app = express();
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you need to change

```
app.set('view engine', jade);
```

to

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Comment: How does this add anything to the answer given by @Lawati97, several months ago?